# Best practise to execute long running PHP scripts

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, magento, cron

We need to distribute software which should contain a PHP script which will run for some minutes. Therefore I am searching a best practise way to do this in 2017.

- **It has to be invoked by an HTTP request**. There should be no HTTP request waiting for some minutes so the script has to run still AFTER the visitor got his HTTP response.
- **It has to run periodically (every night)**. It also should run every night per default (like a cron job). Notice: since the software is going to be distributed to clients there is no way for us to add a cronjob manually (we have no access to our clients servers). Everything should be accomplished within PHP code.

---

(Please note that I read existing blog posts and Stackoverflow questions myself but I could not find a satisfying answer)

Maybe anyone knows how frameworks like Symfony and Laravel or webshops like Magento accomplish such tasks? Still I want to know how to do it by myself in plain PHP without using frameworks or libraries.

Comment: This is a bit off topic of SO, but you want to run it as a non-blocking CLI script.  Not sure if this is best practice, but I have a class for this very thing.  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/BgProcess.php  Works on CentOS and Windows.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Is it true to call this a (really convenient) wrapper around exec() (http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) for UNIX and the COM object (http://php.net/manual/de/class.com.php) for Windows?

Comment: Yes, the windows part was a real pain to get it to run non-blocking.

Comment: Yes, that would be reasonable.  I use that with Code Igniter so it may construct the command with `/` instead of `{spaces}` in the arguments.  Which would be for routing to CI controllers.  I don't recall if I cleaned all the dependencies from that stuff out of that particular copy of it.

Comment: You may also find this one usefull, https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/ProcLock.php  It's a process locking mechanism for PHP.  Basically it stores the Process ID, pid, in a file and only allows you to run one process at a time.  This is useful for keeping Cron from starting multiple copies of a process if it takes longer to run then the Cron cycle time.  You can do multiple processes you just have to name the lock files differently.

Answer (score 6):

Many solutions exist:

- using exec (rather insecure), that triggers a background job (recommended in comments, I would probably prefer symfony process, but insecure nevertheless).
- using a cron to trigger a symfony process every so often, not over http so way more secure.
- using php-fpm, you can send a response without stopping the process using [fastcgi_finish_request](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)
- using a queue system (SQS, RabbitMQ, Kafka and so on).
- using a [cron manager in PHP](https://github.com/Cron/Cron)
- using a daemon and something like supervisord to make sure it runs continuously.

The best solutions are definitely queues and cron, then PHP-FPM, rest of it is just rubbish.

There is absolutely no way for you to run on someone's server without doing something that won't work at some point.

Sidenote: you said you did not want libraries in order to know how to do it yourself, I added links to libraries as reading them may give you a deeper knowledge of the technology, these libraries are really high quality.

Comment: Quick note from the docs: [Symfony Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) __If a Response is sent before a child process had a chance to complete, the server process will be killed (depending on your OS).__

Comment: I believe this is only true if you are not using php-fpm and fastcgi_finish_request though, as it is due to the way the system will kill any child when finishing a script, whild fastcgi_finish_request helps us in the way that the main script (php-fpm) will continue after the response is sent. Am I making sense for you there?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I didn't go that deep into what's happening, but it's always nice to learn something knew. Thanks! So much to learn :)

Comment: `exec ()`  by itself does not trigger a background job, it could be considered splitting hairs though.  So what I mean is that `exec` is still blocking, so it will hold up the current script while it runs.  I would define a background job as asynchronous to the current thread.  You can add `> /dev/null &` to the end of the command (on Linux) to detach it from the current shell.

Comment: Using rabbit dosen't get rid of the need for running a process in the Command Line, as you have to have workers to process your stuff.  Not that it's a bad Idea. I use RabbitMq at work and it works great..  The main benefit though, is that it gives you a separation layer between the publishers and consumers.

Comment: Those things said, you do have some great Ideas!

Comment: Right now I just want to note that Symfony Process is just a wrapper around proc_open(). And I think that the process created with proc_open() cannot live longer than its parent and proc_open()'s main purpose is executing commands and having IPC. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @ThomasDutrion If with "using a daemon" you mean writing a daemon in PHP with pcntl_fork() this is something I also thought about.. but I read there are some downsides to this? What is "supervisord"?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I think there are two ways to start a long running process in PHP via an HTTP request (without letting the user wait for a long time):

- Using FPM and send the response to the user with [fastcgi_finish_request()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php). After the response is sent you can do whatever you want, for example long running tasks. (Here you don't have to start a new process, just continue with PHP).

  ```
  fastcgi_finish_request();
  longrunningtask();
  ```
- Create a new process using one of the following functions. Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to null and put it to the background (you have to do both). To still get output of the new process the new process can write to some log file.

  ```
  exec('php longrunningtask.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
  shell_exec('php longrunningtask.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
  system('php longrunningtask.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
  passthru('php longrunningtask.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
  ```

  Or use `proc_open()` like `symfony/process` does.

---

Notes:

- `symfony/process`: on the docs you can read that you can use FPM and `fastcgi_finish_request()` for long running tasks.
- Security: I can see no built in security risk, you just have to do things right then everything is fine (you could use password protection, validate possible inputs to your commands, etc.).
- For the cron-job-part of the question there is no answer. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: using the ampersand (&) to background the process and routing output is a good idea. I have noticed that the longrunningtask.php can be interrupted/terminated if you restart apache, so this approach doesn't fully sever longrunningtask.php from the place where you ran the exec command. You may encounter difficulties. I have had some luck putting a call to [posix_setsid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setsid.php) in longrunningtask.php.

Answer (score 1):

Magento only runs it cronjobs, if you setup a regular cronjob for Magento. It has a cron.sh, that runs every minute an executes jobs in Magento's queue.

Any Solution to execute long-running tasks via http involves web-server configuration.

Comment: So someone has to edit the cronjob file manually with something like "crontab -e". Maybe it's not a good idea but I think you COULD add a cronjob with PHP: https://www.variomedia.de/faq/Wie-richte-ich-einen-Cronjob-ein/article/86

Comment: normally a php process will run as webserver user (www-data) and will not have the permission to run crontab. Some configurations even completely prevent usage of system(), exec() etc (see safe_mode_exec_dir). In any case server admin will have to messaround will user groups or permissions to make this happen.